# How to visualize branches in git (topology), where git log --graph doesn't show them?

Tags: git

I'm trying to visualizing the git branch topology, but when I use $git log --graph it's been shown as a series of commits.

```
$ git log --graph --all --oneline

* 5c27c47 (tbranch) tbranch commit
* 01a5a93 (HEAD -> master) commit
* c49cb49 rename
* 337bd9a new file added
* bcc3d2c delete new 2
* 16e2af4 new file added
* 6984275 trying -a commit
* 1ff68e2 gif diff reviewed
* 04add98 experincing git diff
* cf34191 changed the text file
* 0ca946e new file added
```

I wanted it to be shown something like this:

```
| * commit

| * commit

| * commit

|/

|*commit
```

Comment: are you missing `--decorate` option?

Comment: I added it, but nothing has changed.

Comment: Why don't you download a UI like [Git Extensions](https://github.com/gitextensions/gitextensions/releases)?

Comment: By checking what I get as output, I can see that you will get the lines when you have (at least) 2 branches to be shown... if there's a single branch to display, you will only get the *s

Comment: I tried it on another repository which has three branches, it's a part of Udacity git course. I keep on getting the same result.

Comment: $ git log --graph --oneline master easy-mode
* d84e1a2 (HEAD -> easy-mode, coins) breaking roid into 2 instead of 3
* 794cbec (master) reparing bullet delay error
* 3884eab (origin/master, origin/HEAD) Add color

Comment: @eftshift0: `--decorate` is already set, probably through `log.decorate`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The graph shown here:

```
* 5c27c47 (tbranch) tbranch commit
* 01a5a93 (HEAD -> master) commit
* c49cb49 rename
* 337bd9a new file added
* bcc3d2c delete new 2
* 16e2af4 new file added
* 6984275 trying -a commit
* 1ff68e2 gif diff reviewed
* 04add98 experincing git diff
* cf34191 changed the text file
* 0ca946e new file added
```

*does* have two branches, but the two branches are linear with each other, not parallel to each other.  So `git log --graph` displays them that way.

More specifically, it appears that the parent of `5c27c47` (the tip of `tbranch`) is `01a5a93` (the tip of `master`, which you have checked-out as well).  The parent of `01a5a93` is `c49cb49`, and so on.  If we draw these horizontally, instead of vertically, we get:

```
...--o--o   <-- master (HEAD)
         \
          o   <-- tbranch
```

where the round `o`s represent the commits without showing their hash IDs.

If you had *this* (where I've added one more commit to `master`):

```
...--o--o--o   <-- master (HEAD)
         \
          o   <-- tbranch
```

then when `git log` prints this graph vertically, you will see what you want to see:

```
* nnnnnnn (HEAD -> master) nnnnnnn's subject
| * 5c27c47 (tbranch) tbranch commit
|/
* 01a5a93 commit
* c49cb49 rename
...
```

but right now there's no need for `git log --graph --all --oneline` to bother doing that, so it doesn't.